# Getting Click Event for Editable Polygon Point (Google Maps API v3)

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps-api-3

When drawing an editable `Polygon` on a map using Google's V3 API, is there some event I could register for that tells me when one of the polygon's points (only made visible by the `editable` flag) is clicked? I want to be able to enable a user to draw a polygon, using right clicks, and "complete" the polygon by clicking on the first point plotted. I begin by creating a `Polygon` of one point, and add each successive point with each right-click. I use the mousemove event to create two "completion" lines, two fainter lines (two `Polylines`) from the last point  plotted to the current mouse position on the map, and from the current mouse position on the map to the first ("anchor") point. When I click on that first point, I'd like to be able to "finish" the `Polygon`, by taking away these completion lines, inferring the intent of the user now to either edit the points already drawn with the handles the editable Polygon provides, or   save the Polygon's coordinates to my application.

Is there a way to do this? (As I've written this, I've thought of one solution: create a small circle, invisible, around the first ("anchor") point, and detect when that invisible circle is clicked. But I wanted to see if there was something built-in in the API that I could use.)

Comment: Are you trying to roll your own polygon editor?  I would suggest using the drawing library instead:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#drawing_tools

Also see events section:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DrawingManager

Comment: @andresf Wasn't aware of the Drawing Library's ability to draw `Polygons`. Thanks for pointing this Google Maps API newbie in the right direction.

Comment: Happy to help.  Will move my comments to the answer section.

Comment: @andresf I rolled my own polygon editor years ago for V2 maps API. Now it's difficult to migrate it V3. My own editor ties into other infrastructure, and so I'm not sure if it's easier to migrate my stuff or to hook the drawing library into my infrastructure. In V2 we used the events, 'endline' and 'cancelline', to answer the question.

Comment: I would have liked the actual answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to roll your own polygon editor? I would suggest using the drawing library instead:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#drawing_tools

Also see events section:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DrawingManager